# Ajax to login users...callback function not working

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

This is my second foray into Ajax and I'm not quite sure how to pull this off.

So I have a modal window that opens when an anonymous user attempts to perform a certain task. The window contains a user signup form that I then $.post to my Django login view.  If username/password are valid, user is logged in an status code of 1 is returned as the response.  IF not, a status of 0 is returned.

When I try to do it outside of js, it works.  However, within my script, it fails.  I think that it has to do with the response content_type and how I'm interpreting it.  I'm not sure.

```
def login_async(request):       
if request.method=='POST' and len(request.POST['username'])<20 and len(request.POST['password'])<20:
    username=request.POST.get('username', '') #probably need to script tags here
    password=request.POST.get('password', '')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        status=1
        response=HttpResponse()
        response['Content_Type']="text/html"
        response.write(status)
        return response
    else:
        status=0
        response=HttpResponse()
        response['Content_Type']="text/html"
        response.write(status)
        return response




$('input#login').click(function(event){
    $.post("/login_async/", {username:$('input[name=username]').val(), password:$('input[name=password]').val()}, //could also use $(this).serialize() here to capture all form inputs
        function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $('#login').dialog("close");
                }
    });
    });
```

What's the problem here? I initially tried to return the response as JSON but I couldn't figure out how to make serialize.serializers("json",status) work.  I kept getting an error.

One last question...

If I get a valid status (user is signed in), that will influence the behavior of modal windows on the page.  The modal windows open based on logged in status.  If a user is signed in, one set of windows open on a click event, and vice versa.  This toggle is dependent on Django context {% user.is_authenticated %}.

That context renders only once right, on page load?  Can I do anything to communicate the status change to the modal windows that's secure from easy hacks?

Comment: Try changing the url to "/login_async". Also, have you looked at the console? I would try creating an event handler for a request fail & success, and have it show an alert whenever either is happening so you know whether the request failed or succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Content-Type`. If that doesn't fix your problem, try adding a [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) parameter at the end of the `$.post` call.

```
$.post("/login_async/", {}, function(data){
  // fancy stuff
}, "html");
```

Comment: yeah, thanks haochi that seemed to do the trick.  My larger question still stands, though.  I've now logged in my user, but I'm not sure how to communicate that fact to my modal windows, whose behavior is otherwise dictated by an {% if user.is_authenticated %} django context variable

Comment: @Brendan Maybe have a variable that lives inside the global scope called, say `var user_logged_in = {% user.is_authenticated %};`. After the log in process, just update the variable with the response. In your event handlers just add an `if (user_logged_in) { } else { }`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I thought it over more and realized that I should just unbind the existing click event handlers on the modal windows and then bind new event handlers depending on the ajax response.

I love programming